# C performance and choice of functions parameters

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I'm making a little bignum library as an exercise (it is my first little project, i'm a newbie). I'm using the c language.
I defined a structure number in this way:

```
typedef struct number{
char *mantissa;
long exponent;
enumSign sign;
}number;
```

(I'm including the structure because I don't know if size matters here),
and some functions to do basic arithmetic operations. 
My question is:
is it more efficient if i use:

`number do_sum(number n, number q)`

or,

```
void do_sum(number *n, number *q, number *result)
```

?
I tried to record the time of execution in both cases (the functions being almost identical) but the results were not consistent.
Could you please explain also what happens in both cases?

Comment: In the case of a pointer, it is sufficient to push a pointer to the stack. If it is not a pointer all members must be stacked on the stack.

Comment: With big number functions, certainly the timing performance of the interface is trivial compared to function execution.  Code to ease of use and development.  IMO, `int do_sum(const number *n, const number *q, number *result)` and retuning an error indicator is more useful

Comment: You need to make sure that you do not accidentally modify the inputs inside your functions (so use `const`). The pointer approach should give better performance if you make enough calls to the function (say in a loop).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the compiler could pass by pointer "behind the scenes" for the return value, and also for the arguments if the function doesn't modify them

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the answer to questions of this kind, you need to

- Learn how to view the assembly output of your compiler in each case.  All decent C compilers have an option to produce assembly output.  If you do that, you will see that one version is considerably more complicated than the other, both for the caller and for the callee.  The version which is more complicated is the one returning a `struct`.  And greater complexity usually (but not always) means worse performance.
- Use a profiler to try each case and see which one performs better.  Spoiler: the version that returns a `struct` will perform worse than the version that accepts a pointer to an existing `struct`.

Performance notwithstanding, C is quite fast either way, so I would recommend that you do not pay so much attention to performance while learning to code.  The kind of performance that tends to matter is *algorithmic* performance, which is language agnostic.  The performance of individual low level operations hardly ever matters much.

Comment: Excellent answer; not clear why someone downvoted it.  Although I doubt that greater complexity of assembly usually means worse performance;  program compiled with -O3 is always far larger than with -Os

Answer (score 0):

In general, unless the particular implementation calls for otherwise, it is preferred to pass pointers to large structs rather than structs themselves.

In case you are passing the whole struct into the function, its copy is created in memory, which takes time (and RAM space). On the other hand, if you are passing a pointer, only integer that contains an address gets copied. It probably does not matter for the struct of your size, because it's so small (hence no observed difference), but you may see a difference in handling large structs in slow embedded systems.